# Mask with jquery

Tags: jquery, django, mask

I applied a money format mask and did not accept the first digit to be 0. However, the following characters are still accepted "e, -, + ,." obs:field is decimal.The mask works but accepts these characters described

I applied a money format mask and did not accept the first digit to be 0. However, the following characters are still accepted "e, -, + ,." obs:field is decimal.The mask works but accepts these characters described

I applied a money format mask and did not accept the first digit to be 0. However, the following characters are still accepted "e, -, + ,." obs:field is decimal.The mask works but accepts these characters described

**below code with django**

```
valor_compra = forms.DecimalField(label=u'Valor de Compra (R$)', required=False, max_digits=11, decimal_places=2, min_value=1)
valor_residual = forms.DecimalField(label=u'Valor Residual (R$)',
                                    required=False, max_digits=11,
                                    decimal_places=2, min_value=1)
```

**below the code in js**

```
        //Empresa
        $('#id_cnpj').mask('00.000.000/0000-00');
        $('#id_telefone1').mask('(00) 000000000');
        $('#id_telefone2').mask('(00) 000000000');
        $('#id_fax').mask('(00) 000000000');
        $('#id_cep').mask('00.000-000');

        //Adiciona mascara e não aceita numero 0
       var options = {
            onKeyPress: function (valor, e, field, options) {
                let item = parseInt($('#valor_compra').val().replace(/[,.]/g, ''));
                if (item === 0) {
                    $('#valor_compra').val('').change();
                }
                var masks = ['000000000.00', 'ZZ'];
                var mask = (valor.length >= 1) ? masks[0] : masks[1];
                $('#valor_compra').mask(mask, options);
            },
            translation: {
                'Z': {
                    pattern: /[1-9]/, optional: false
                },
            },
            reverse: true
        };

        $('#valor_compra').mask('ZZ', options);

        var options = {
            onKeyPress: function (valor, e, field, options) {
                let item = parseInt($('#valor_residual').val().replace(/[,.]/g, ''));
                if (item === 0) {
                    $('#valor_residual').val('').change();
                }
                var masks = ['000000000.00', 'ZZ'];
                var mask = (valor.length >= 1) ? masks[0] : masks[1];
                $('#valor_residual').mask(mask, options);
            },
            translation: {
                'Z': {
                    pattern: /[1-9]/, optional: false
                }
            },
            reverse: true
        };

        $('#valor_residual').mask('ZZ', options);

        // Data
        $('#id_data_aquisicao').mask('00/00/0000');
        $('#id_data_aquisicao').datepicker({
            endDate: '0d',
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            language: 'br'
        });

        $('#id_data_fabricacao').mask('00/00/0000');
        $('#id_data_fabricacao').datepicker({
            endDate: '0d',
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            language: 'br'
        });

        $('#id_garantia').mask('00/00/0000');
        $('#id_garantia').datepicker({
            format: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
            language: 'br'
        });

        /*  Esse método é executado quando o modal se fecha.
            É necessário para quando o modal se fecha ele apague os seus dados.
            Caso ele não esteja presente o primeiro modal aberto persistirá mesmo
            que outros modais de outros tipos sejam abertos. */
        $("#myModal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
            $(this).data('bs.modal', null);
        });

        var max_height = Math.max($('#dados-basicos').height(), $('#dados-adicionais').height());
        $('#dados-basicos').height(max_height);
        $('#dados-adicionais').height(max_height);
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Please edit your question to finish specifying the exact problem. First, you're repeating the same thing 3 times, the last sentence is abruptly finishing mid-sentence and it's not clear what works and what doesn't. Don't show us js code for fields that don't relate to your question and give us examples of input you expect to work/not work and what behavior you see.